# Extends simple object from another simple object C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to extend a simple object from another simple object in order to don't pass all the attributes one by one as follows:

```cs
var param = new { id, name }

var param2 = new { param.id, param.name, description }
```

Exists any possibility to do something like that and get the same result?:

```cs
var param = new { id, name }

var param2 = new { param, description }
```

Comment: [Spread operator like in es6](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2879) shows a request for such a language feature, doesn't seem to have gone anywhere.

Comment: **If it is ok** to make those named classes, you could do that with a CTOR that takes params accordingly to the requirement.